# Manually call javax validation fails

Tags: java, validation

i learning validaton on javax and i dont understand why my code not work.

i try to validate with Validator and it always pass and i should not.

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Car car = new Car();
Set<ConstraintViolation<SettingsEntity>> violations = validator.validate(car);

System.out.println("nomber of error = " + violations.size());
```

this output:

```
nomber of error = 0
```

my car:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Positive;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Car implements Serializable{

    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    String MAKE;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    String MODEL;

}
```

Comment: i (heart) when low voter vote and dont know why . zikomo bulu wosayankhula

Comment: that is because you don't have NotNull or NotEmpty or NotBlank ... by default "NULL" values are valid. Just the "Size" means it's optional but if specified, validation will be performed.

Comment: oh what this is dumb